# Using differential calculus to prove a fact on exponents

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, factorial

I have done some calculations recently on squares and cubes and $4^{th}$ powers, and so on, and I found out something. It goes like this:

$$
\begin{align}
f(x)&=x^2\\
f'(x)&=2x^1=2x\\
f"(x)&=2
\end{align}
$$

This is only for the rate of change in the squares. For the rate of increase, you get:

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=x^2+(x^2+x+1)+(x^2+x)\\
f'(x)&=2x+(2x+1)+(2x+1)\\
f''(x)&=2+(2)+(2)\\
&=6
\end{align}
$$

To make any noticeable pattern appear, we have to add another term or two. the cubes' differentiation would be this:

$$
\begin{align}
f(x)&=x^3+(x^3+x^2+x+1)+(x^3+x^2)\\
f'(x)&=3x^2+(3x^2+2x+1)+(3x^2+2x)\\
f''(x)&=6x+(6x+2)+(6x+2)\\
f'''(x)&=6+(6)+(6)\\
&=18
\end{align}
$$

Notice the pattern yet? No? Here's one more:

$$
\begin{align}
f(x)&=x^4+(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)+(x^4+x^3)\\
f'(x)&=4x^3+(4x^3+3x^2+2x+1)+(4x^3+3x^2)\\
f''(x)&=12x^2+(12x^2+6x+2)+(12x^2+6x)\\
f'''(x)&=24x+(24x+6)+(24x+6)\\
f''''(x)&=24+(24)+(24)\\
&=72
\end{align}
$$

Do you notice the pattern yet?  It is this:

$$\text{if} f(x)=x^z+(x^z+x^{z-1}+x^{z-2}+\cdots+x^0)+(x^z+x^{z-1}), \\
\text{then} f''{^{(\text{z times})}}''(x)=3(z!)$$

Basicially, in the equation $x^z+(x^z+x^{z-1}+x^{z-2}+\cdots+x^0)+(x^z+x^{z-1})$, which is the rate of increase in a cube or polytope, the $z^{th}$ derivative (or, in calculus terms, you could put it as $\frac{d^zf}{dx^2}$)is always $3\times z!$

My question is this: is there any practical use for this? My friend said it may have something to do with the rate that the exponential function increases (as in $3z! $ added to a number added to a number and so on z times until you get $x^z$), but I am not sure. Is it for that? If not, where is it useful? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could show this without having to guess a pattern - you have $3x^z+2x^{z-1}+x^{z-2}+...+z^0$. Taking derivatives $z$ times leaves you with $3z!$. I don't understand what is special about this function though.

Comment: just a remark on notation: the $n$-th derivative of a function $f$ is commonly denoted as $f^{(n)}(x)$ as [shown here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Lagrange.27s_notation).

Comment: @Dando18 that is interesting...   i'll use that next time, if it pops up again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x^z + (x^z + x^{z-1} + \cdot\cdot\cdot + x^0) + (x^z + x^{z-1})$.

First, rewrite this as $f(x) = 3x^z + (x^{z-1} + x^{z-2} + \cdot\cdot\cdot + x^0) + (x^{z-1}) $ Now we know that the $n$-th derivative of $x^n$ is $n!$ and it's trivial that the $n$-th derivative of $x^k$ is $0$ for any integer $0 < k < n$.

Since all the terms after $3x^z$ become $0$ as we differentiate, we only have to concern ourselves with the first term.

$$ \frac{d^z}{dx^z}\left[ 3x^z \right] = 3 \cdot \frac{d^z}{dx^z}\left[ x^z \right] = 3z!$$

*Addendum:* Why is $\frac{d^n}{dx^n} [x^n] = n! \,$ ?
As you did in your post, write out the first couple derivatives to notice the pattern.

$$ \begin{align*}
f(x) &= x^n \\
f'(x) &= n x^{n-1} \\
f''(x) &= n (n-1) x^{n-2} \\
f'''(x) &= n (n-1) (n-2) x^{n-3} \\
f^{(k)}(x) &= \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}x^{n-k} \\
f^{(n)}(x) &= \frac{n!}{(n-n)!} x^{n-n} = \frac{n!}{1} x^0 = n!
\end{align*} $$